# Return latest row ordered by ID while using group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, subquery

I have 2 tables, A and B contains some data for example

```
   TABLE A                 TABLE B
+----+-------+     +----+------+--------+
| id | title |     | id | a_id | status |
+----+-------+     +----+------+--------+
|  1 | apple |     |  1 |    1 |      0 |
|  2 |  eggs |     |  2 |    1 |      1 |
+----+-------+     |  3 |    1 |      2 |
                   |  4 |    1 |      3 |
                   |  5 |    1 |      0 |
                   |  6 |    1 |      1 |
                   |  7 |    2 |      0 |
                   |  8 |    2 |      1 |
                   |  9 |    2 |      2 |
                   | 10 |    1 |      0 |
                   | 11 |    1 |      3 |
                   +----+------+--------+
```

I want to select fruits from table A and join with table B and get latest status record (by ID).

My tables contains about 10k of fruits and 100+k of statuses.

So result will look like

```
+------+---------+------+--------+----------+
| a.id | a.title | b.id | b.a_id | b.status |
+------+---------+------+--------+----------+
|    1 |   apple |   11 |      1 |        3 |
|    2 |    eggs |    9 |      2 |        2 |
+------+---------+------+--------+----------+
```

I can do this with group by sql script like this

```
SELECT * FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id GROUP_BY a.id
```

but it gets first item from table B so results are not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
select a.title,
       substring_index(group_concat(status order by id desc), ',', 1) as laststatus
from b join
     a
     on a.id - b.a_id
group by a.title;
```

EDIT:

If you just want the *last* record from b, you can do:

```
select a.title, b.status
from b join
     a
     on a.id - b.a_id
order by b.id desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Just a side question can you use ORDER BY inside GROUP BY?

Comment: @Mihai . . . An `order by` after a `group by` orders the results of the query.  An `order by` in a subquery is more questionable.  The ANSI standard says the results do not have to be ordered after the subquery is executed.  MySQL documentation does not address this issue, as far as I've found.  I would avoid queries that depend on the results of a subquery being returned in a particular order.

Comment: The substring_index, group_concat does the trick! Excellent but can u explain how it works? thanks!

Comment: @ypercube why not very efficient? I've tried this and got result in ~0.5 sec and while using subquery it takes ~55sec

Answer (score 0):

All regs ordered by b.id

```
SELECT * 
FROM a
INNER JOIN b
ON a.ID = b.A_ID
ORDER BY b.ID desc;
```

Just 1 reg.

```
SELECT * FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON A.ID = B.A_ID
WHERE A.ID = (select max(B.A_ID) from B);
```

Comment: Edited my question, this is not solution, because it returns all rows, not grouped :)